# Overriding a method in the superclass' superclass in java?

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
class A
{
  public void Foo() {}
}

class B extends A
{
}

class C extends B
{
  public void Foo() {}
}
```

Does C's Foo() override A's even though B did not override it? Or do I have to add a stub in B that calls the super's method for each one I want to override in C?

Comment: Yes this will override A's implementation for instances if C only.  Instances of A and B will use A.Foo().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though B did not mention it, `Foo` should still be available to it due to inheritance. By extension, then, `Foo` is also available to subclass C and should be able to be overridden thanks to polymorphism.

Instances of C, therefore, will use `c.foo()` (however it is defined), where as instances of A and B will make use of `a.foo()` because they have not yet been overridden.

Comment: Presumably then: A a = new C(); a.Foo(); will call C.Foo()?

Comment: Erm, yes, but that's a rather confusing naming convention for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Yes C overrides Foo() of A.

This is due to inheritance, though B doesn't override Foo() , Foo() is inherited from A by B.

And as C extends B, Foo() is inherited by C and overriding happens as C defines Foo().